# Opening SSL URLs with Python

Tags: python, linux, django, ssl, mechanize

I'm using mechanize to navigate pages, it works pretty well.

Unfortunately I have a **random error** come up, by random I mean it occasionally appears.

> URLError at /test/
>
> urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1325: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac>
>
> ---

**I really need help on this one :)**

---

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and found that `PycURL` works way better than `urllib`.

[Django request XML file with SSL IO error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134666/django-request-xml-file-with-ssl-io-error)