# Django request XML file with SSL IO error

Tags: xml, django, ssl, urllib, ioerror

I'm making a Django website and am fairly new. In this webapp I need to use this API which will spit out an xml file with the requested data from the database.
Basically the API URL is:

https://adminuser:password@url.to.database.com/database.getdata?arg=1&arg2=0

So in my python views.py I have:

```
def fetch_xml(url):
  import urllib
  import xml.etree.cElementTree as xml_parser

  u = urllib.URLopener(None)
  usock = u.open(url)
  rawdata = usock.read()
  usock.close()
  return xml_parser.fromstring(rawdata)
```

Which I got from http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/integrate_web_apis_into_your_django_site/

However, I received the following error right at the line `usock = u.open(url)`

```
IOError at /webapp/

[Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

I read on the `urllib` documentation that an IOError is thrown if the connection cannot be made.
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html
Also, on Wikipedia a "Bad record MAC" fatal alert means "Possibly a bad SSL implementation, or payload has been tampered with. E.g., FTP firewall rule on FTPS server."

But what I don't understand is that when I paste the URL into my browser it works fine and spits out an XML file.

I also thought (as a long shot) it might be my Apache installation so I checked that mod_ssl was being loaded by typing `apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES` in terminal and it is loaded as shared.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My coworker got the API to work in PHP so I took a look at his code and he was using `cURL`. I found out there is a python version called `PycURL`. After installing PycURL, I ripped out the `urllib` code and used PycURL instead.

```
import pycurl

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, authenticate_url)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSLVERSION, 3)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, False)
c.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2)
c.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)')

outputXML = c.perform()
c.close()
```

I guess `urllib`is not as robust as PycURL.